# How to remove horizontal and vertical lines without degrading the image quality in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-tesseract

I am trying to remove horizontal and vertical lines from a image. This image is generated from a pdf using pdf2jpg library. Upon removal of the horizontal and vertical lines this image will be fed to pytesseract to extract words and their individual co-ordinates. Here I am just extracting the full text for testing purpose.
I am new to OpenCV. I have written this code by accumulating code snippets from different websites including stack overflow. The code works almost perfectly other than there are some occasional remnants of vertical lines. This remnants are confusing the tesseract and sometimes is being treated as I, 1 or |. Also it seems like number of misreads(like s is read as 5, I is read as 1 or | and vice versa) by tesseract is higher for the processed image than the original image. I think the reason for that being the font sharpness is lower than the original image that we started with. What changes can be done to this code which will remove those remnants of vertical line without affecting the font sharpness. Any suggestions or guidance in right direction will be heavily appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
from importlib import invalidate_caches
from pytesseract import image_to_string
#from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from pdf2jpg.pdf2jpg import convert_pdf2jpg
from PIL import Image
import sys
import cv2
import numpy

def pre_process(image):
    if isinstance(image, str):
        image = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    else:
        # image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        pass
    #Convert the image to true black n white from grayscale
    threshold, image_bin = cv2.threshold(image, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    #Invert the image to change white to black and vice versa
    image_inv = 255-image_bin
    
    #Define kernels for horizontal and vertical lines
    kernel_len = numpy.array(image).shape[1]//100
    vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, kernel_len))
    horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_len, 1))
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 2))

    #Remove anything that is not a vertical line
    image_inv1 = cv2.erode(image_inv, vertical_kernel, iterations=3)
    vertical_lines = cv2.dilate(image_inv1, vertical_kernel, iterations=3)

    #Remove anything that is not a horizontal line
    image_inv2 = cv2.erode(image_inv, horizontal_kernel, iterations=3)
    horizontal_lines = cv2.dilate(image_inv2, horizontal_kernel, iterations=3)

    #Add horizontal and vertical lines to get all lines
    image_vh = cv2.addWeighted(vertical_lines, 0.5, horizontal_lines, 0.5, 0.0)
    image_vh = cv2.erode(~image_vh, kernel, iterations=2)
    threshold, image_vh = cv2.threshold(image_vh, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # Make a inverted copy of original grayscale image
    org_img_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(image)
    #Apply mask of all lines
    final_image_inv = cv2.bitwise_and(org_img_inv, org_img_inv, mask=image_vh)
    #Invert again to get clean image without lines
    image = cv2.bitwise_not(final_image_inv)
    cv2.imshow("final", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return image

if __name__ =="__main__":
    pdf_path = sys.argv[1]
    images = convert_pdf2jpg(pdf_path, "temp", dpi=100, pages="ALL")
    result = ""
    for image_path in images[0]["output_jpgfiles"]:
        # with Image.open(image_path) as image:
            # text = image_to_string(image)
            # result = "\n".join((result, text))
        image = pre_process(image_path)
        #image = pre_process(image)
        text = image_to_string(image)
        result = "\n".join((result, text))
    # print(result)
    with open("text.txt", "w") as out:
        out.write(result)
        # pre_process(image_path)
        # break
```

Please find the attached pdf, which I am using as my input pdf for the code and a snip for processed image for reference. The code can be triggered from command prompt using

```
python .\read_pdf_ocr.py path_to_pdf_file
```

Environment details:

1. Python:            3.7.9
2. Libraries:

   - opencv-python:    4.4.0.46
   - pdf2jpg:           1.0
   - pytesseract:       0.3.6
3. Tesseract-OCR - open source OCR engine:      v5.0.0-alpha.20200328

[Snip of processed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9BqF.png)

[Test PDF with table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IikvRSo3YnMjIEjLbSQaVv1-fn3En9Ps/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I upvoted your question, but please make sure that the code is the [_minimal_ reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, please consider adding some comments to the code to help others.

Comment: To remove horizontal and vertical lines, your image needs to be rotated first so that the lines are more horizontal and vertical.

Comment: As an intermediate solution you can indicate the area where the text is located. This would remove the need for more processing.

Comment: @Suthiro - Thanks a lot. This is my first post in Stack Overflow. I will add the comments in some time. This code will be part of a larger code base that I am building to create a data extraction framework from pdfs. I have uploaded the code in git, and planning to make it public when it is stable. I have provided the minimum portion which I thought would be required to recreate the scenario.

Comment: @fmw42- yes that's true. If you check the attached PDF u will see that they are perfectly horizontal and vertical, still they are leaving a faint line mark which I somehow can't get rid of. I tried to play with the kernel size but no luck. Horizontal lines seems to be gone, but vertical lines are still there. Can see the output image in snip of processed image. For PDFs with tilted scanned image we will have to incorporate this rotation though. Thanks for the idea

Comment: @thymen - When I am feeding images generated from the PDFs to pytesseract for some PDFs the words inside tightly packed tables are just being ignored and they are not available in the final result. I suspect this problem is being caused by tesseract for being confused be the lines in close proximity of the letters. So that's why I am trying to get rid of the lines altogether. Since I am trying extract the location of each individual words present in the page I can't provide a specific region. Though I guess in case of extracting table data this logic might help.

Comment: I can't post the PDFs that I am facing this issue explained in earlier comment since they contain sensitive information. I could not recreate that issue with ms word generated PDFs since ms word tends to keep a decent amount of margin between the text and cell border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `line-detector` to detect the lines in the given image.

After you convert the image using `convert_pdf2jpg`

Find the edges of the image. You can use `Canny`.

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("ex.png")
img_gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_cny = cv2.Canny(img_gry, 50, 200)
```

[Canny-applied-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1fsg.png)

Part of the canny image:

[image]

Now we can use the `line-detector` to find the coordinates of the image.

```py
lns = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector().detect(img_cny)

img_cpy = img.copy()

for ln in lns:
    x1 = int(ln[0][0])
    y1 = int(ln[0][1])
    x2 = int(ln[0][2])
    y2 = int(ln[0][3])

    cv2.line(img_cpy, pt1=(x1, y1), pt2=(x2, y2),
             color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=5)

    print("Coords: ({}, {})->({}, {})".format(x1, y1, x2, y2))
```

When we run the code:

[image]

Output:

```sh
Coords: (8, 6)->(586, 6)
```

So the width of the table is `580 pixel`. (586 - 6)

[image]

Output:

```sh
Coords: (589, 28)->(589, 6)
```

So, the distance between two consecutive line is nearly `22 pixel` (28 - 6)

and there are 37 lines.

How about we draw each line same as the background color?

We know the distance between two consecutive line, start and end of the horizontal lines.

```py
for _ in range(0, 37):
    cv2.line(img, pt1=(6, y1), pt2=(590, y1),
             color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=5)
    print("Coords: ({}, {})->({}, {})".format(6, y1, 590, y1))
    y1 += 20
```

Result:  [Horizontal lines removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTTTu.png)

Sample:

[image]

If you look at the last sentence of the output:

```sh
Coords: (6, 726)->(590, 726)
```

So the ending coordinate is `726`. Too remove the vertical-line we need to find the starting coordinate since we already know the ending coordinate.

[image]

Output:

```sh
Coords: (8, 6)->(586, 6)
Coords: (589, 28)->(589, 6)
Coords: (69, 8)->(69, 24)
Coords: (337, 8)->(337, 24)
```

Th first coordinates give the starting points, `589, 69, 337` and `6`

The first vertical line coordinates are: `(6, 6)->(6, 726)`
The second vertical line coordinates are: `(69, 6)->(69, 726)`
The third vertical line coordinates are: `(337, 6)->(337, 726)`
The fourth vertical line coordinates are: `(589, 6)->(589, 726)`

```py
cv2.line(img, pt1=(6, 6), pt2=(6, 726),
         color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=5)

cv2.line(img, pt1=(72, 6), pt2=(72, 726),
         color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=5)

cv2.line(img, pt1=(337, 6), pt2=(337, 726),
         color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=5)

cv2.line(img, pt1=(589, 6), pt2=(589, 726),
         color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=5)
```

Result: [Vertical-lines-removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL5ac.png)

Sample:

[image]

Now, when you read the text from the output image:

```
LINE 1
LINE 2
LINE 3
.
.
.
SOME RANDOM TEXT FOR LINE 1 CELL 1.
SOME RANDOM TEXT FOR LINE 2 CELL 1.
SOME RANDOM TEXT FOR LINE 3 CELL 1.
SOME RANDOM TEXT FOR LINE 4 CELL 1.
.
.
.
1AM OTHER TEXT FOR LINE 1 CELL 2
1AM OTHER TEXT FOR LINE 2 CELL 2
1AM OTHER TEXT FOR LINE 3 CELL 2
1AM OTHER TEXT FOR LINE 4 CELL 2
```

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("ex.png")
img_gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_cny = cv2.Canny(img_gry, 50, 200)

# lns = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector().detect(img_cny)
#
# img_cpy = img.copy()
#
# for ln in lns:
#     x1 = int(ln[0][0])
#     y1 = int(ln[0][1])
#     x2 = int(ln[0][2])
#     y2 = int(ln[0][3])
#
#     cv2.line(img_cpy, pt1=(x1, y1), pt2=(x2, y2),
#              color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=5)
#
#     print("Coords: ({}, {})->({}, {})".format(x1, y1, x2, y2))
#
#     cv2.imshow("img_cpy", img_cpy)
#     cv2.waitKey(0)

y1 = 6

for _ in range(0, 37):
    cv2.line(img, pt1=(6, y1), pt2=(590, y1),
             color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=5)
    print("Coords: ({}, {})->({}, {})".format(6, y1, 590, y1))
    y1 += 20

cv2.line(img, pt1=(6, 6), pt2=(6, 726),
         color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=5)

cv2.line(img, pt1=(72, 6), pt2=(72, 726),
         color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=5)

cv2.line(img, pt1=(337, 6), pt2=(337, 726),
         color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=5)

cv2.line(img, pt1=(589, 6), pt2=(589, 726),
         color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=5)

cv2.imshow("lns", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(txt)
```

Comment: That looks perfect. Thanks a lot. I will try to implement it today itself. I will mark it as answer once I have implemented it. In case of difficulty, I might come back with more question. Please bear with me. :)

Comment: It seems I am missing something. First thing i had to change for this line of code "cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector().detect(img_cny)" is I had to uninstall opencv-python and install opencv-contrib-python 4.4.0.46. Yet I am not getting similar result. The horizontal lines are partially identified First horizontal lines is identified as "Coords: (442, 98)->(101, 97)". Also lots of characters are being identified as smaller lines. Does saving the image from pdf page as jpg or png makes any difference?

Comment: I've implemented the code using opencv and opencv-contrib-4.0.0, but getting similar results are not important. "Coords: (442, 98)->(101, 97)". Then your table width is `341 pixel`. Now you need to find the distance between two consecutive horizontal lines. It's normal `line-detector` finds a lot characters.

Comment: Understood. I was under assumption that cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector().detect detects only large lines. but that's incorrect. I have applied this finding lines and making them white logic after separating vertical and horizontal lines and it is working perfectly. I am marking this as answer.